# Saving realm relationships does not persist them

Tags: java, android, realm

I have a list of [articles](https://github.com/MetalMatze/Krautreporter/blob/8d4e0e0d0d2056cce41f5c461ea7216bf47cba60/app/src/main/java/de/metalmatze/krautreporter/models/Article.java).
Those articles are inserted by using `realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate();` which works perfectly fine.

Now each article has an authorId which should not be persisted. Rather I want to find the stored [author RealmObject](https://github.com/MetalMatze/Krautreporter/blob/8d4e0e0d0d2056cce41f5c461ea7216bf47cba60/app/src/main/java/de/metalmatze/krautreporter/models/Author.java) and set its relationship for the article.

```java
Author author = realm.where(Author.class).equalTo("id", article.getSerializedAuthor()).findFirst();
article.setAuthor(author);
```

Somehow this does not seem to be persisted by realm.

The same applies to the [image RealmObject](https://github.com/MetalMatze/Krautreporter/blob/8d4e0e0d0d2056cce41f5c461ea7216bf47cba60/app/src/main/java/de/metalmatze/krautreporter/models/Image.java), just that I iterate before saving.

Here's the full snippet.

```java
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(articles.data);

for(Article article : articles.data) {
    Author author = realm.where(Author.class).equalTo("id", article.getSerializedAuthor()).findFirst();
    article.setAuthor(author);

    for (Image image : article.getSerializedImages().data) {
        if (article.getImages() == null) {
            article.setImages(new RealmList<Image>());
        }
        article.getImages().add(image);
    }
}
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Please let me know if you need more information.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm was just trying to put every single statement inside a `realm.beginTransaction();` and `realm.commitTransaction();`. But that doesn't help either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Christian from Realm here. You keep manipulating the standalone objects you just copied to Realm, which won't work as they are still standalone objects and not "proper" Realm objects. You can read more here: http://realm.io/docs/java/0.80.0/#creating-objects and in the JavaDoc http://realm.io/docs/java/0.80.0/api/io/realm/Realm.html#copyToRealm-E-

So if you change you code to something like the below, it should work:

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        List<Article> realmArticles = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(articles.data);

        for(Article article : realmArticles) {
            Author author = realm.where(Author.class).equalTo("id", article.getSerializedAuthor()).findFirst();
            article.setAuthor(author);

            for (Image image : article.getSerializedImages().data) {
                article.getImages().add(image);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! You're right. I thought that this was saved call-by-reference. Doesn't seem to be that way. Later I'm gonna post a link on github to my updated version of this problem.

Comment: So here's my fixed version: https://github.com/MetalMatze/Krautreporter/blob/feaa251b29cc59702a9e4af38c2039b6ce767f78/app/src/main/java/de/metalmatze/krautreporter/api/Api.java#L78 I need to manually iterate over the images because getSerializedImages() has an @Ignore annotation.

Comment: Yes, this particular part of the API is not great, but is unfortunately dictated by limitations in the Java language itself.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using GSON? If so, did you follow the example as outlined in http://realm.io/docs/java/0.80.0/#gson?

Comment: Yes, I did. https://github.com/MetalMatze/Krautreporter/blob/8d4e0e0d0d2056cce41f5c461ea7216bf47cba60/app/src/main/java/de/metalmatze/krautreporter/api/Api.java#L30 The Problem isn't retrieving the data from the server. I've checked it, it's all there. But persisting it with realm doesn't work.