# Realm object not fully persisted

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm having trouble trying to understand how realm.io persist/save objects.

I have 3 Objects (Inventory, InventoryItem and Product);
When I create a Inventory containing InventoryItems it works fine until i close the app. When i re-open the app all InventoryItems loses the reference to Product and start to show "null" instead.

Strange thing is all other attributes like Inventory reference to InventoryItem is persisted fine. Just problem with Products.

this is how i'm trying to do:

**Model**
**Product**

```
public class Product extends RealmObject {
@PrimaryKey
private String id;
@Required
private String description;

private int qtdUnityType1;
private int qtdUnityType2;
private int qtdUnityType3;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public int getQtdUnityType1() {
    return qtdUnityType1;
}

public void setQtdUnityType1(int qtdUnityType1) {
    this.qtdUnityType1 = qtdUnityType1;
}

public int getQtdUnityType2() {
    return qtdUnityType2;
}

public void setQtdUnityType2(int qtdUnityType2) {
    this.qtdUnityType2 = qtdUnityType2;
}

public int getQtdUnityType3() {
    return qtdUnityType3;
}

public void setQtdUnityType3(int qtdUnityType3) {
    this.qtdUnityType3 = qtdUnityType3;
}
```

}

**Inventory**

```
public class Inventory extends RealmObject {

@PrimaryKey
private String id;

@Required
private String type;

@Required
private Date createdAt;

@Required
private String status;

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

private RealmList<InventoryItem> listItems;


public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public Date getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
}

public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
}

public RealmList<InventoryItem> getListItems() {
    return listItems;
}

public void setListItems(RealmList<InventoryItem> listItems) {
    this.listItems = listItems;
}
```

}
**InventoryItem**

```
public class InventoryItem extends RealmObject {

@PrimaryKey
private String idItem;

private Inventory inventory;

 private Product product;

public Product getProduct() {
    return product;
}

public void setProduct(Product product) {
    this.product = product;
}


private Date expirationDate;

private int qtdUnityType1;

private int qtdUnityType2;

private int qtdUnityType3;

private int qtdDiscard;

public String getIdItem() {
    return idItem;
}

public void setIdItem(String idItem) {
    this.idItem = idItem;
}

public Inventory getInventory() {
    return inventory;
}

public void setInventory(Inventory inventory) {
    this.inventory = inventory;
}


public Date getExpirationDate() {
    return expirationDate;
}

public void setExpirationDate(Date expirationDate) {
    this.expirationDate = expirationDate;
}

public int getQtdUnityType1() {
    return qtdUnityType1;
}

public void setQtdUnityType1(int qtdUnityType1) {
    this.qtdUnityType1 = qtdUnityType1;
}

public int getQtdUnityType2() {
    return qtdUnityType2;
}

public void setQtdUnityType2(int qtdUnityType2) {
    this.qtdUnityType2 = qtdUnityType2;
}

public int getQtdUnityType3() {
    return qtdUnityType3;
}

public void setQtdUnityType3(int qtdUnityType3) {
    this.qtdUnityType3 = qtdUnityType3;
}

public int getQtdDiscard() {
    return qtdDiscard;
}

public void setQtdDiscard(int qtdDiscard) {
    this.qtdDiscard = qtdDiscard;
}
```

}

**and finally one of the millions ways i tried to persist**

```
  realm.beginTransaction();

 Inventory inventory = realm.createObject(Inventory.class);
 inventory.setId(id);
 inventory.setCreatedAt(new DateTime().toDate());
 if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.rbInventario) {
     inventory.setType("Inventário");
 } else {
     inventory.setType("Validade");
 }
 inventory.setStatus("Aberto");

 RealmList<InventoryItem> inventoryItems = new RealmList<>();
 RealmResults<Product> productsRealmResults = realm.allObjects(Product.class);


 for (int i = 1; i <= productsRealmResults.size(); i++) {
     InventoryItem item = realm.createObject(InventoryItem.class);
     item.setIdProduct(productsRealmResults.get(i - 1).getId() + " - " + productsRealmResults.get(i - 1).getDescription());
     item.setProduct(productsRealmResults.get(i - 1));
     item.setIdItem(i + "-" + id);
     item.setInventory(inventory);        
     item = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(item);
     item = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(item);
     inventoryItems.add(item);
 }
 inventory.setListItems(inventoryItems);


 realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(inventory);
 realm.commitTransaction();
```

I already looked trough some answers here like this one:
[stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355576/saving-realm-relationships-does-not-persist-them)
and the Java-examples (person, dog, cat)

provided with the API

but I can't understand how to properly insert this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting a list of InventoryItem elements which are not added to the Realm database.

Change `InventoryItem item = new InventoryItem();` to `InventoryItem item = realm.createObject(InventoryItem.class);`

Also, the inventoryItems themselves aren't stored in Realm db. Add `realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(inventoryItems)` after the loop.

Comment: Already tried that with 
`Inventory inventory = realm.createObject(Inventory.class);` and
`InventoryItem item = realm.createObject(InventoryItem.class);`

and same thing, Inventory in InventoryItem is persisted fine, but product only the first time, when I close the app, becomes null.

All InventoryItem are in Realm but Product attribute becomes null

Comment: I'm testing right now, any other attribute other than Product that I set in InventoryItem is perfect persisted. I can't see what am I missing here.

Comment: Can you add the code snippet where your create Inventory object

Comment: Hey Roberto, I edited the post someone removed this part by mistake

Comment: And you don't need these two lines: `item = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(item);`

Comment: Just tried before and after this line  `inventory.setListItems(inventoryItems);` same thing :/ and removed those lines too

Comment: How do you check that inventoryItem doesn't have a reference to the product?

Comment: I have another class with a list and I do this 

 `RealmResults<InventoryItem> results = realm.where(InventoryItem.class).equalTo("inventory.id", getIntent().getExtras().getString("ID_INVENTORY")).findAllSorted("idProduct");
 itemsAdapter = new InventoryItemAdapter(this, results, true);`

finally the InventoryItem in adapter has all atributtes except Product which is null (just after I close the app, first time works fine). 

Just ignore this `findAll("idProduct")`, I already did some changes...

Comment: Hey. I created a sample project based on your code. You can see it here: https://gist.github.com/RobertoArtiles/c0e42001c72f17adcc3d When you look at the LogCat or connect debugger you can see it persists the Product. So it could be that there is something wrong with the rest of your code, or that you make a wrong assumption that the Product is not persisted, but in fact something else doesn't work. Make sure that you verify with logs (or via debugging) that the Product is actually null. Keep in mind that in debugger you have to use getters to see the fields value of Realm's objects.

Comment: Thank I will try your code and try to extract realm db for analysis to see what am I missing. I'm verifying via debug that Product is null, but as I you said could be something with realm instance or something like that. 
As you show me how to propperly insert the realm objects. I will accept your answer.

Comment: Finally I found my mistake... It was really, really stupid. 

On previous Class I was doing  `realm.clear(Product.class);` and re-inserting the Product... after that of course all products references in the InventoryItem become null. Thank you very much for you help!

Comment: Sure. Great to hear it!